# SQL query to retrieve number of keys in database

Tags: sql, count, sql-server-2012, key

How can I retrieve the total number of primary keys, and all secondary keys, unique indexes for very table in a database? Is there any function in SQL that will allow me to get this?

I am using SQL Server 2012 database

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012 database

Comment: EXEC SP_HELP 'table_name'. [sp_help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This query against the `sys.indexes` system catalog view might give you what you need (or at  least it's a starting point):

```
SELECT 
    IndexName = i.name,
    TableName = OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id),
    i.index_id,
    i.type_desc,
    i.is_unique,
    i.is_primary_key,
    i.is_unique_constraint
FROM sys.indexes i
```

It lists all indexes for all tables in your current database, and show index name, table name, index type (clustered or non-clustered), and flags for primary key, unique index etc.

You can read a lot more about [SQL Server catalog views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and what information they might have for you on MSDN!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select  object_name(object_id), 
         sum(case when is_primary_key = 1 then 1 else 0 end)  'Primary_Count',
        sum(case when is_unique_constraint = 1 then 1 else 0 end) 'Unique_Count'
from sys.indexes m
group by object_id,case when is_primary_key = 1 then is_primary_key else is_unique_constraint end
```

Comment: I guess u want the count rather than displaying them as u asked for count